# Crear index con un campo substring

Tags: mysql, indices

Es posible crear un index en mysql pero el campo indice siendo un substring ?
Por ejemplo:

```
Create NON-UNIQUE INDEX nombreInidice on nombreTabla (SUBSTRING(nombreCampo FROM 1 FOR 4)) USING HASH;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partir de [MySQL 5.7.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-6.html), puedes utilizar una [columna auto generada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-6.html#mysqld-5-7-6-generated-columns) para almacenar la sub-cadena que te interesa y crear un índice sobre esa columna, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE MiTabla (
      id int
    , MiCampo CHAR(50)
    , MiSubCampo CHAR(10) AS SUBSTRING(MiCampo, 8, 10) STORED
    , INDEX(MiSubCampo)
)
```

Comment: ¿Qué alternativas hay para los usuarios que usen `MySQL < 5.7.6`?

Comment: Puedes lograr el mismo efecto creando una columna que sea mantenida por un trigger y basar tu índice en esa nueva columna.